# sample distribution of sample variance for a random sample

Tags: statistics

I'm given that n=2 and a simple table showing this...

x        0          1        5
p(x)    .25        .25      .5

I found the sample distribution for the sample mean to be this...
_
x      0      .5     1       2.5     3     5
  _
p(x) .0625   .125   .0625    .25    .25   .25

I also discovered that the mean is 2.75, but I'm lost on how to find the sample variance for these points...I'd appreciate any feedback or tips!

Answer (score 1):

There are, unfortunately, two different quantities that are sometimes referred to as "sample variance".  For $n$ values $y_1, \ldots, y_n$,  the "biased sample variance" is 
$\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \overline{y})^2$, and the "unbiased sample variance" is
$\dfrac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \overline{y})^2$, where in both cases $\overline{y} = \dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ is the sample mean.  You should check which one you are being asked about.

Since $n=2$ and there are just $3$ possible values, you just have $9$ outcomes to consider,  each consisting of a possible value for $y_1$ and a possible value for $y_2$.
Find the value of the sample variance for each.
For example, if $y_1 = 0$ and $y_2 = 5$, then $\overline{y} = (0+5)/2 = 2.5$ and
the unbiased sample variance is $(0-2.5)^2 + (5-2.5)^2 = 12.5$.
Then the probability of the sample variance having value $v$ is the sum of the probabilities
of the outcomes where the sample variance is $v$.